# jquery doesn't accept variable as selector, string works

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap

I wrote this script which runs when a message from MQTT is recieved:

```
function onMessageArrived(message) {

    var fullmsg=message.destinationName.split("/"); 
    var msg=fullmsg[3]; //retrieves deviceId 2780 (string)
    var payload=message.payloadString; //value of device recieved
    console.log(msg, payload); // gives 2870, 100
    if(payload == 100) {
        $('#2780').bootstrapSwitch('setState', true); //works and toggles switch
    } else if (payload == 0) {
        $("#" + msg).bootstrapSwitch('setState', false); //doesn't work
    }
    //client.disconnect();
};
```

The idea is that this script toggles a bootstrap switch on or off. I would like to do this dynamicaly based on the devideId I get of the variable msg. When I manually type in the selector '#2780' all works. When I use the variable from msg it doesn't work. It must be something silly, but I just started with jquery so need some help.

Comment: $('#2780').bootstrapSwitch('setState', true);...shouldn't the id be 2870?

Comment: should work as shown assuming that the value of the variable is as shown...and that the element exists when the code is run. Provide a [mcve] that reproduces problem

Comment: You're using both 2780 and 2870 in the code. Which one is it?

Comment: That's a typo in the comment. Should be 2780.

Answer (score 0):

Add:

```
console.log("Setting switch to false");
```

...before:

```
$("#" + msg).bootstrapSwitch('setState', false);
```

That way you can verify whether or not bootstrap is even being called.  Earlier, you state that payload = 100:

```
console.log(msg, payload); // gives 2870, 100
```

Given that, wouldn't

```
else if (payload == 0)
```

prevent the switch from being set to false?

Comment: I checked both suggestions, console logs the correct state. So the first if statement doesn't prevent the else if following that. Thanks for the suggestion!